# How to select a string between two & in oracle

Tags: oracle

`O&103122&00:00:00&&          ,  &SECS&1&19.0000&&&          ,  &`
`&`

`10/01/2022 - 10/31/2022&TSIMM:TRUNK SIGNALING - ON NET Charge&&gid=2060155&`
`&10/01/2022 - 10/31/2022&TSIMM:TRUNK SIGNALING - ON NET Charge&&gid=2060155&`

In the above Strings I need to select only below String in Oracle DB

`SECS`
`TSIMM:TRUNK SIGNALING - ON NET Charge`
`TSIMM:TRUNK SIGNALING - ON NET Charge`

Please help me on this Thanks...

`TRIM(' '  &'   &')`

Comment: Please provide your current attempt and describe what is the issue with it. And why, for example, `gid=2060155` is not in the output?

Comment: Column 1: &11/01/2011 - 11/30/2011&Off NetTrunkSignaling/Route&&gid=2048771&
Column 2 : O&103111&00:00:00&&          ,  &SECS&1&758084.0000&&&          ,  &
Column 3:  &11/01/2011 - 11/30/2011&TCAP-On Net/OPC&&gid=2048617&

Comment: In the above 3 column I need to select only Column 1 :Off NetTrunkSignaling/Route          Column 2: SECS   Column 3: TCAP-On Net/OPC   In Oracle

Comment: I have tried Like this SELECT SUBSTR(trans_desc, INSTR(trans_desc, '&') + 25) AS trans_desc
FROM   ilm_stg_rc_ar_txn